# (Android studio 2.1) "SDK does not contain any platforms. error"

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting the "SDK does not contain any platforms. error" after installing *Android Studio 2.1*. How to fix it?

[image]

I have JAVA_HOME 1.7.0_80 and error download and install SDK

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default **sdk** was installed under the

`C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\` directory

Not inside the

`C:\Users\<user_name>\.AndroidStudio2.1\`

So now change your **sdk** path by browsing above specified path. And you have to add **JAVA_HOME** path under **System Variable**.

You can change the sdk path by copy pasting the entire sdk directory from C Drive to any new location.