# sdk does not contain any platforms

Tags: android, android-studio

My main problem is after installing the android studio 2.3 I faced a problem of

> "Android Studio Error: Error:Create Process error=216, This version of
>   %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running"

I found this article:

[Android Studio Error: Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c)

Tried their solution but had the 2'nd problem:

> "sdk does not contain any platforms"

Screenshot: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ2X5.png)

I have checked this too but was not helpful:

[(Android studio 2.1) "SDK does not contain any platforms. error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037119/android-studio-2-1-sdk-does-not-contain-any-platforms-error)

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running?

Comment: windows 8.1 pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error may be if you are trying to add path location of JDK in SDK location path I am not sure but see the difference in this Image.[Image Highlighting JDK path location and SDK path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Fbr.png)