# android studio and sdk linux

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, sdk

I download all this compressed files:

- android_m2repository_r47
- build-tools_r26-linux
- platform-tools_r26.0.0-linux_15-52-51
- tools_r25.2.5-linux

and extracted to /home/amanjaro/Android/Sdk/
but when determine the path it give me **sdk does not contain any platform**

[image show that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNxEg.png)

I can't install SDK using android studio as in my country the internet is very slow.

Comment: You need a platform to SDK to run. Download a platform such as JellyBean or Nougat

Comment: any thing from this page https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-70-api-24-nougat-direct.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Android studio 2.1) "SDK does not contain any platforms. error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037119/android-studio-2-1-sdk-does-not-contain-any-platforms-error)

Comment: It is no solve my problem